# Stoping web service in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, web-services

is it possible to stop a web service from executing?

I have a flex web application that searches clients with both full name and client id, when searching by name sometimes the usuer just types the last name and it takes a long time.

Since the app is used when clients are waiting in line, I would like to be able to stop the search and use their full name or id instead, and avoid waiting for the results and then having to search the user manually within the results.

thanks

**edit:** Sorry, I didn't explain myself correctly, when I meant "web service" I actually meant mx.rpc.soap.mxml.WebService, I want to stop it from waiting for the result event and the fault event. thanks.

Comment: Why does it take so long to search by last name?  Isn't it indexed?  Why are clients waiting in line?  Seems like you're trying to solve a problem that really shouldn't exist.

Comment: its indexed, it takes a long time because the servers cant take the load and has plenty of records, people wait in line because the that is the way the organization works, and yes, it shouldn't exist, but as of right now, it does, and must be solved. thanks, hope you have an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

You could use `disconnect()` to remove any pending request responders, but it also disconnects the service's connection.  Then call `initialize()`.

**/Update**

You cannot stop the web service from executing, because that's beyond the Flex app's control, but you can limit the processing of the web service's response.  For instance on the app, have a button like `Cancel Search` which sets a boolean `bSearchCanceled` to true.
The result handler for the web service call checks `bSearchCanceled`; if true just return.

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a `cancel(..)` method explicitly for this purpose, though it is a little burried. Using the cancel method will cause the result and fault handlers not to be called and will also remove the busy cursor etc.

Depending on how you run your searches (ie. separate worker process etc), it is also possible to extend this by added in a `cancelSearch()` web service method to kill these worker processes and free up server resources etc.

```
private var _searchToken:AsyncToken;

        public function doSearch(query:String):void
        {
            _searchToken = this.searchService.doSearch(query);
        }

        protected function doSearch_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
        {
            trace("doSearch result");
            trace("TODO: Do stuff with results");
            _searchToken = null;
        }

        protected function doSearch_faultHandler(event:FaultEvent):void
        {
            trace("doSearch fault: " + event.fault);
            _searchToken = null;
        }

        public function cancelSearch():void
        {
            var searchMessageId:String = _searchToken.message.messageId;

            // Cancels the last service invocation or an invokation with the
            // specified ID. Even though the network operation may still
            // continue, no result or fault event is dispatched.
            searchService.getOperation("doSearch").cancel(searchMessageId);
            _searchToken = null;
            trace("The search was cancelled, result/fault handlers not called");

            // TODO: If your web service search method is using worker processes
            // to do a search and is likely to continue processing for some time,
            // you may want to implement a 'cancel()' method on the web service
            // to stop any search threads that may be running.
        }
```